I want to make an app that sends an http request with a button press and it doesn't work
i am using okhttp3 to send the request and it just WORKS once and any other button press just does nothing
 private fun makeGetRequest() {

            val client = OkHttpClient()
            val request = Request.Builder().url("http://192.168.1.54/trigger").build()
            val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : okhttp3.Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                runOnUiThread {
                    textView.text = "failed to send request"
                }

            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    runOnUiThread {
                        textView.text = response.body.toString()

                    }

                }
            }

            })
        
    }

if someone can help me i'd appreciate it very much
i'm stuck on it for so long now
i tried to clear the cache, restart the app programmatically, and nothing works

Can you please share the code of 'any other button' and provide some more details with what is the expected outcome and what is going wrong?

Please Kindly share the code and error so we can help you better.
But I guess the issue is with the HTTP protocol of another buttons request address.

You need to add the Internet permission to your manifest file:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


To use HTTP protocol (not HTTPS), you need to add this code to your manifest file:

<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.54</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

Normally, Android doesn't allow you to send request over HTTP protocol due to security reasons. so you need to add the above code and define the domain name or the IP address that you need to access.

I added that and the app does send an http request, but it's failing to send another one once I press the button again...
